# send indexpath to Firebase (like button)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table view and the cells are populated with data from Firebase. In each cell there is a like button, when I like a button in a particular cell, it captures the ID of that cell and creates a node in Firebase to let me know the button was clicked (liked). Before the button is clicked, it is white and after it is clicked it turns red. Then if it is clicked again (unliked) it turns white.

```
 @IBAction func LikeClicked(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {

        let LikedRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Likes").child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!)

        let indexPath = self.selectedIndex
        let post = self.posts![(indexPath?.row)!] as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.key = post["postID"] as? String

        let cell = TableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! ProfileTableViewCell


        if cell.Like.currentImage == #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Hearts Filled-50 (2)"){
            cell.Like.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Heart-50"), for: .normal)
            // cell.RedLike.isHidden = true

            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Likes").child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!).child(self.key!).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error \(error)")
                }else{

                }})
        } else{

            LikedRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


                if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {


                    var LikeStatus = postsDictionary[self.key!] as? String ?? ""

                    if self.key == LikeStatus
                    {
                        // cell.Like.isHidden = true

                        cell.Like.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Hearts Filled-50 (2)"), for: .normal)

                    }


                }})



            LikedRef.updateChildValues([self.key!: self.key!])


        }


    }

  cell.Like.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LikeClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    cell.Like.tag = indexPath.row
    print(indexPath.row)
    cell.Like.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

My problem is when I like one button on a specific cell, all the like buttons in every cell turns red. but I only want the cell I click to turn red and when I leave the app and come back all the buttons are back to being white. I want whatever button the logged in user likes to remain red regardless of if the user exits the app or not.

Comment: Where is this IBAction `LikeClicked ` located? In your viewController or in your tableViewCell class?

Comment: @Glenn its located in the view controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I spent an hour or so to just give you an idea how you can do what you need to do. Liking and unliking from your custom `UITableViewCell`. I've explained in each line of code I made the details. I hope this helps you out. Let me know if you have questions. Remember this is just one of the many ways you can do your task.

**MyViewController.swift**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, MyCustomCellDelegate {

    // This is the array of keys that we
    var likedDataKeys = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Load here the 'Likes' stuff and store its in a datasource for reference or store as well its keys.
        // If data is liked, store to likedDayaKeys the key of your data.

        FirebaseCall {
            if liked {
                self.likedDataKeys.append(keyOfYourData)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ....

        // Set the image.

        let dataKey = yourDatasource[indexPath.row] // get the key or whatever data you need

        // Set the delegate and key
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.dataKey = dataKey

        if likedDataKeys.contains(dataKey) {
            cell.image = redImageLike
        } else {
            cell.image = whiteNormalLikeImage
        }

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - MyCustomCellDelegate

    func myCustomCell(userDidTapLikeWithDataKey dataKey: String) {
        // So now we can get the dataKey of the cell that is being liked or unliked.
        // Check from the self.likedDataKeys if the tapped cell is liked or not.

        if self.likedDataKeys.contains(dataKey) {
            // If it is there, then we should call the unlike Firebase.
            // Also remove it from the self.likedIndexPath and reload the tableView to update the image.

            let index = self.likedDataKeys.index(of: dataKey)
            self.likedDataKeys.remove(at: index)

            // Call now the unlike Firebase.

        } else {
            // If it is not there, then we should call the like Firebase.
            // Also store it to the self.likedIndexPAth
        }
    }
}
```

**MyCustomCell.swift**

```
protocol MyCustomCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    // This is the delegate that will help us send the dataKey reference to the viewController
    // Whenever the user taps on the like button in the cell.
    func myCustomCell(userDidTapLikeWithDataKey dataKey: String)
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    // This will be called in the viewController, pass here the self of the viewController
    weak var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegate?

    // Make sure to pass here the key from the cellForRow of the viewController's tableView delegate.
    var dataKey = ""

    @IBAction func LikeClicked(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {
        // Call the delegate to inform the viewController
        self.delegate?.myCustomCell(userDidTapLikeWithDataKey: self.dataKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped so much! Thank you so so much!